# NPM and Windows PATH - Not working anymore

Tags: path, npm, windows-10

This is NOT a normal path problem.

The Windows 10 machine I'm working on got the PATH variable erased after trying to install OpenSSH .

I've (almost) recovered the PATH manually but , I've got a persistant problem with NPM commands ..

This might be dead simple for anyone , let's justa add the ".../bin" directory and problem solved.

I've done everything to make it work again , but I don't get why it's not working anymore !

I've even reinstalled nodejs ( with npm )..nothing  .

If you're good enough with Windows systems , and you can help me , please don't hesitate to comment .

Thank you all.

Comment: Which commands are failing? Is the directory that contains `npm.cmd` in PATH?

Comment: any command starting with npm in cmd ..

Comment: module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3

Comment: The previous comment is the debug message printed in the terminal , and it's printed twice the same .. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Never mind , I've figured it out :

The real reason was the double entry for npm's path ( old style and new style) .

Leaving just the nodejs path solved the problem.